# Problem in texturing a cube

Tags: texturing

I add a texture to a cube. The texture is an image. I set Coordinates to Generated and Projection to Cube. The rendering is perfect: the texture is replicated on all 6 faces of the cube.
But if I use the Texture or Material Display Modes in the 3D View the texture is applied only on 2 faces of the cube.
Why ?

The attached image show the problem with Material Display Mode[image]

Comment: Did you remember to add a material before the texture?
Instead of using Coordinates to Generated and Projection to Cube,use simple UV unwrapping and do each face separately. You can manipulate the size, shape, and position of the image in the UV editor.

Answer (score 1):

Blender's viewport has limited support for generated and object coordinates.

GLSL preview materials only support a subset of Blender node material textures and features as stated in [this bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T36956) and [this one too](https://developer.blender.org/T36956)

You can fake it or workaround it using node materials, as shown in this [video](https://plus.google.com/+V%C3%ADtProch%C3%A1zkaWireSoul/posts/TrhdMH1UoCv)

Comment: It seems that GLSL preview materials only support the Flat Projection Type

Comment: That's right. Cycles material preview recently received an upgrade to support other projection types like cube sphere and tube. It will be in the next release I think,  but it doesn't work for Blender Internal or game engine materials.